# I am not able the analytics tag to the wordpress home page?

Tags: wordpress

Hi Friends my site is wordpress but we are create static homepage now i am unable to add the analytics code to the homepage. But the code is applied for all the pages like smartfence, [security fencing](http://www.smartfence.in/smart-fence/)

Website: http://www.smartfence.in

Answer (score 0):

easiest to solve your query is to make that static page as template an assign it to the page for eg you assign it to the homepage as

```
/*Template Name:Home*/
```

After you assign the page as home then you can use wordpress condition to make sure you only have that anayltics code in home page

```
<?php if(is_page('yourpageidhere')): ?>
analytics code here
<?php endif; ?>
```